# Windows Phone 7 download pure HTML as string?

Tags: html, string, windows-phone-7

I have been trying to get a clear answer on how to download a page's HTML as a string for months, but have made zero progress. I can mess with all of the parsing myself, and I'll be able to figure out where it needs to fit into the application as I mess around with it. I would be very very grateful if someone could give me a clear code block to download a page's HTML as a string from a given url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the *simplest* way is to use `WebClient`:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += YourEventHandler;
client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

where the event handler then takes whatever action it needs to.

However, it's worth bearing in mind that `WebClient` does rather a lot of work on the UI thread (despite the "async" part) - if this is for a production app, you probably want to use `WebRequest` directly. That's significantly more work (you end up with a `Stream` from the `WebResponse`, so you need to use the appropriate string encoding and construct a `StreamReader` around it in order to read a string).

Answer (score 1):

System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

docs are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a project I posted that demonstrated two ways of downloading html as a string and the relative merits of each.

[WebClient, HttpWebRequest and the UI Thread on Windows Phone 7](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/594e1422-3b69-4cd2-a09b-fb500d5eb1d8)

HttpWebRequest gives you a nice UI performance benefit for a little extra work.